# Proper syntax in new SASS modules: @use instead of @import

Tags: sass, module

I have been using @import to pull in external stylesheets (animate.css, for instance) into my main, .scss stylesheets for quite some time.

I now discovered that @import is being deprecated and has been replaced with @use. However, I am unable to find a proper example of the syntax @use is expecting when importing external files.

With @import, I would have something like this:

```
@import url('../assets/css/animate.css');
```

The above would go grab the animate.css file in my /assets/css/ directory, and embed it into my main .scss stylesheet.

From the documentation here, https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use, I see that @use is expecting modules to be loaded via their namespace, and to create a namespace from an external resource, I should use:

```
@use '<url>' as <namespace>;
```

So I tried the following:

```
@use '../assets/css/animate.css' as animation;
```

However, that actually causes an error when compiling, and even if it did not, what am I supposed to do with 'animation' once it is a namespace?

Should I just go back to including separate, individual stylesheets in the `<head>`, or has someone out there figured out how to make @use work in the way I was using @import before?